# Uniform Blocks and Buffers

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've been trying to implement a class which creates and allows modifications to a uniform buffer object using OpenGL 3.3. The class should be usable regardless of the layout qualifier in the uniform block's definition (either std140, shared or packed). It seemed to be working fine until I refactored phong shaders to use uniform blocks instead of uniforms. Since then the application can't find the uniform blocks in the phong shaders, but works perfectly fine for all the other shaders..
It's lead me to believe that it must be an error I've made while reformatting the phong shaders, but I've looked over it countless times and can't find anything. The only thing I could think of was that the compiler was removing the uniform blocks from the shaders because it believes they're not being used, but they definitely are being used so it couldn't be that.
The shaders are definitely being compiled successfully and are linked before calling glGetUniformBlockIndex().

Every time I create a shader the two uniform blocks I currently use are looked for and then bound to a binding point if found.

```
    programID = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(programID, vertexID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentID);

    glLinkProgram(programID);
    glUseProgram(programID);

    GLuint matricesIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(programID, "MatrixBlock");
    if (matricesIndex == GL_INVALID_INDEX)
        cout << "Could not get index for uniform block MatrixBlock in " << name << endl;
    glUniformBlockBinding(programID, matricesIndex, 0);

    GLuint lightsIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(programID, "LightBlock");
    if (lightsIndex == GL_INVALID_INDEX)
        cout << "Could not get index for uniform block LightBlock in " << name << endl;
    glUniformBlockBinding(programID, lightsIndex, 1);
```

This is where I see the that both of the uniform blocks are not being found in the Phong shaders. The vertex and fragment shaders are below:
Vertex:

```
// phong.vert
#version 330

const int maxLights = 30;

layout (std140) uniform MatrixBlock
{
    mat4 modelMat;
    mat4 viewMat;
    mat4 modelViewMat;
    mat4 projectionMat;
    mat3 normalMat;
};

layout (std140) uniform LightBlock
{
    int numLights;
    vec4 position[maxLights];
    vec4 direction[maxLights];
    vec4 ambient[maxLights];
    vec4 diffuse[maxLights];
    vec4 specular[maxLights];
    vec3 attenuation[maxLights];
    float cosCutoffAngle[maxLights];
};

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_Position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 in_Normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 in_TexCoord;

out VS_OUT
{
    vec3 vs_normalVec;
    vec3 vs_vertexVec;
    vec2 vs_texCoord;
    vec3 vs_lightVec[maxLights];
    float vs_lightVertDistance[maxLights];
    float vs_attenuation[maxLights];
} vs_out;


void calculateVectors()
{
        //Translate vertex position into view coordinates. 
    vec4 vertexPosition = modelMat * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

        //Find vertex position in view coordinates. Since the viewer is at the origin, simply negate the position. 
    vs_out.vs_vertexVec = normalize(-vertexPosition).xyz;

        //Translate normal of the vertex to view coordinates. Uses the normal matrix. 
    vs_out.vs_normalVec = normalize(normalMat * in_Normal);

    for(int i=0; i<numLights; ++i)
    {
            //Calculate the vector from the vertex position to the light source in view coordinates. 
        vs_out.vs_lightVec[i] = position[i].xyz - vertexPosition.xyz;
            //Calculate the distance of the above vector before normalising it. 
        vs_out.vs_lightVertDistance[i] = length(vs_out.vs_lightVec[i]);
        vs_out.vs_lightVec[i] = normalize(vs_out.vs_lightVec[i]);

        vs_out.vs_attenuation[i] = 1 / 
            (attenuation[i].x + 
            attenuation[i].y*vs_out.vs_lightVertDistance[i] + 
            attenuation[i].z*vs_out.vs_lightVertDistance[i]*vs_out.vs_lightVertDistance[i]);
    }
}

void main(void) 
{
    calculateVectors();

    vs_out.vs_texCoord = in_TexCoord;

    gl_Position = projectionMat * modelViewMat * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

}
```

And Fragment:

```
//phong.frag
#version 330

// Some drivers require the following
precision highp float;

struct materialStruct
{
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
};

const int maxLights = 30;

vec3 reflection;

layout (std140) uniform LightBlock
{
    int numLights;
    vec4 position[maxLights];
    vec4 direction[maxLights];
    vec4 ambient[maxLights];
    vec4 diffuse[maxLights];
    vec4 specular[maxLights];
    vec3 attenuation[maxLights];
    float cosCutoffAngle[maxLights];
};

uniform materialStruct material;
uniform sampler2D textureUnit0;
uniform bool textured = true;

in VS_OUT
{
    vec3 vs_normalVec;
    vec3 vs_vertexVec;
    vec2 vs_texCoord;
    vec3 vs_lightVec[maxLights];
    float vs_lightVertDistance[maxLights];
    float vs_attenuation[maxLights];
} fs_in;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 colour;


vec4 calculateLightColour(int i)
{
        //Calculate colour of light and object material.
        //Ambient intensity
    vec4 ambientI = ambient[i] * material.ambient;

        // Diffuse intensity
    vec4 diffuseI =  diffuse[i] * material.diffuse;
    diffuseI = diffuseI * max(dot(fs_in.vs_normalVec, fs_in.vs_lightVec[i]), 0.0) * fs_in.vs_attenuation[i];

        // Specular intensity
    vec4 specularI = specular[i] * material.specular;
        //Specular Intensity = Ks*(R.V)^(alpha)*Is
    specularI = specularI * pow( max( dot( reflection, fs_in.vs_vertexVec ), 0 ), material.shininess ) * fs_in.vs_attenuation[i];

    return ambientI + diffuseI + specularI;
}

vec4 calculateLight(int i)
{
        //Calculate reflection light makes to the surface. 
    reflection = reflect( -fs_in.vs_lightVec[i], fs_in.vs_normalVec );

    if(cosCutoffAngle[i] == 0 && direction[i] == vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    {
        return calculateLightColour(i);
    }
    else
    {
            //Calculate the direction vector of the light in view space. 
        vec3 spotDirection = normalize((position[i] - normalize(direction[i])).xyz);

            //Get dot product of spotlight direction and vertex vector. 
        float dotProduct = dot(fs_in.vs_lightVec[i], -normalize(direction[i].xyz));
        //float dotProduct = dot(fs_in.vs_lightVec[i], -spotDirection);

        if(dotProduct > cosCutoffAngle[i])
        {
            return calculateLightColour(i);
        }
        else
            return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    vec4 lightColour = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    for(int i=0; i<numLights; ++i)
    {
        lightColour += vec4(calculateLight(i).rgb, 0.0);
    }

    if(textured)
        colour = lightColour * texture(textureUnit0, fs_in.vs_texCoord);
    else
        colour = lightColour;
}
```

Any help finding a problem in the shaders would be a great help. If there's no apparent errors there any suggestions about what else might be the problem would be appreciated.

Something else I was wondering about Uniform Blocks in OpenGL is that the Superbible 6th Edition's chapter on Uniform Buffers says that you need to use the name of the uniform block followed by the the elements' names when getting offsets to the uniforms. For example

```
GLchar *names[] = {
"MatrixBlock.modelMat",
...
...
};
```

And then use glGetUniformIndices and glGetActiveUniformsiv to populate the buffer correctly. But this method of naming the elements didn't work for me, and neither did using an instance name, which I saw suggested a few places too. 
What worked for me was just using the element names, for example:

```
GLchar *names[] = {
"modelMat",
...
...
};
```

Is there any particular reason for these discrepancies?